# Logarithmic Plot for a Graph (PHP or JS)

Tags: javascript, php, graph, canvasjs, jpgraph

I have tried with things like canvasJS, Jpgraph, Google Graph, etc but I can't seem to make it look similar to this, in the sense of it being Vertical.

Google Chart Attempt:

```
google.charts.load('current', {packages: ['corechart', 'line']});
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawBasic);

function drawBasic() {

  var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();


  data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
      ['X', 'Item1', 'Item2'],

           ['0',  0,      0],
           ['100',  749.8942093,       749.8942093],
           ['1000',  865.9643234,   865.9643234]
  ]);

  var options = {
  orientation: 'vertical',
    hAxis: {
      title: 'Time'
    },

    vAxis: {
      title: 'Popularity'
    }

  };

  var chart = new 
google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));

  chart.draw(data, options);
}
```

Does anyone have experience making something like this?

[image: logchart]

Comment: What have you tried so far? What went wrong?

Comment: Well, where to start... So, with google, I put up the example under the chart above.

Answer (score 0):

This resolved the issue as adding the type to both the y and x-axis and including a range for both as well.

```
  var layout = {
  width: 700,
  height: 700,
xaxis: {
  type: 'log',
  range: [3,5]  // Log Range.  10^n
},
yaxis: {
  type: 'log',
  range: [-2,3]  // Log Range.  10^n
}
};
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Comment: Roger that, I will modify sir.